# Phalcon's Volt engine generates error in jQuery block when using elseif conditional

Tags: php, phalcon, volt

I'm getting weird PHP error when using Phalcon's Volt engine in my project. The case seems to be very simple but although I have checked my code many times I can't seem to get working the simple if-elseif-endif structure.

The template code is here, it is placed in Javascript block in context of jQuery callcack function:

```
{% if table.form.rendered_in == 'offcanvas' %}
            //offcanvas form
            //set attributes

            $(row).find('td.edit-control').

                attr('data-source', '{{table.form.full_action_url}}?get_form').
                attr('data-canvas', 'body').
                attr('data-target', '#rightSlider').
                attr('data-toggle', 'offcanvas').

                click(function () { 
                    console.log('! show edit form: '+record_id);    
                    //edit_one(record_id);
                    if (!right_offcanvas_visible) {

                        //request form with ajax
                        var url = $(this).attr('data-source');
                        var data = {
                            'choose_record': [record_id]
                        };

                        //console.log('Serialized data: '+data);    
                        //$('div#rightSlider').offcanvas('show');
                        TASK.Ajax.Post(url, data, function(response) {  
                            $('div#rightSlider').find('div.rightSliderContent').html(response);
                            //$('div.offcanvas').offcanvas({canvas: 'body'}); // todo: make it work!
                            console.log('! edit one record form set up');    
                        });

                    }

                });

            //delete    
            $(row).find('td.delete-control').

                attr('data-source', '{{table.form.full_action_url}}?get_delete_form').
                attr('data-canvas', 'body').
                attr('data-target', '#rightSlider').
                attr('data-toggle', 'offcanvas').

                click(function () { 
                    if (!right_offcanvas_visible) {

                        //request form with ajax
                        var url = $(this).attr('data-source');
                        var data = {
                            'choose_record': [record_id]
                        };

                        TASK.Ajax.Post(url, data, function(response) {  
                            $('div#rightSlider').find('div.rightSliderContent').html(response);
                        });

                    }

                });

        {% elseif table.form.rendered_in == 'page' %}
            //on same page above the table

            $(row).find('td.edit-control').
                attr('data-source', '{{table.form.full_action_url}}?get_form').
                click(function () { 
                    console.log('! show edit form above table: '+record_id);    
                    var url = $(this).attr('data-source');
                    var data = {
                        'choose_record': [record_id]
                    };

                    TASK.Ajax.Post(url, data, function(response) {  
                        $('div#form-page-main').html(response);
                        $('html, body').animate({ //scroll smoothly to form
                            scrollTop: $('div#form-page-main').offset().top - config.scrollDistanceFromTop
                        }, config.timeAnimateToAjaxForm);
                    });

                });            


            $(row).find('td.delete-control').
                attr('data-source', '{{table.form.full_action_url}}?get_delete_form').
                click(function () { 
                    console.log('! show delete form above table: '+record_id);    
                    var url = $(this).attr('data-source');
                    var data = {
                        'choose_record': [record_id]
                    };

                    TASK.Ajax.Post(url, data, function(response) {  
                        $('div#form-page-main').html(response);
                        $('html, body').animate({ //scroll smoothly to confirmation
                            scrollTop: $('div#form-page-main').offset().top - config.scrollDistanceFromTop
                        }, config.timeAnimateToAjaxForm);
                    });

                });

        {% elseif table.form.rendered_in == 'modal' %}
            // rendered in modal window

            $(row).find('td.edit-control').
                attr('data-source', '{{table.form.full_action_url}}?get_form').
                attr('data-target', '#largeModal').
                attr('data-toggle', 'modal').
                click(function () { 
                    console.log('! show edit form in modal: '+record_id);    
                    var url = $(this).attr('data-source');
                    var data = {
                        'choose_record': [record_id]
                    };

                    TASK.Ajax.Post(url, data, function(response) {  
                        $('div#largeModal').find('div.modal-body').html(response);
                    });

                });            


            $(row).find('td.delete-control').
                attr('data-source', '{{table.form.full_action_url}}?get_delete_form').
                attr('data-target', '#smallModal').
                attr('data-toggle', 'modal').
                click(function () { 
                    console.log('! show delete form in modal: '+record_id);    
                    var url = $(this).attr('data-source');
                    var data = {
                        'choose_record': [record_id]
                    };

                    TASK.Ajax.Post(url, data, function(response) {  
                        $('div#smallModal').find('div.modal-body').html(response);
                    });

                });

        {% endif %}
```

The error is generated possibly by Volt compiler at first elseif referenced below, volt file doesn't get compiled into PHP.

```
{% elseif table.form.rendered_in == 'page' %}
```

The error says:
*Unexpected ENDIF in .../app/views/partials/grideditor.volt on line 307*

The if-elseif-endif structure works nicely elsewhere in Javascript blocks. Which makes things even more odd is that when I replace the elseif with multiple if-endif, if-endif, ... as below, everything works fine.

```
{% if table.form.rendered_in == 'offcanvas' %}
            //offcanvas form
            //set attributes

            $(row).find('td.edit-control').

                attr('data-source', '{{table.form.full_action_url}}?get_form').
                attr('data-canvas', 'body').
                attr('data-target', '#rightSlider').
                attr('data-toggle', 'offcanvas').

                click(function () { 
                    console.log('! show edit form: '+record_id);    
                    //edit_one(record_id);
                    if (!right_offcanvas_visible) {

                        //request form with ajax
                        var url = $(this).attr('data-source');
                        var data = {
                            'choose_record': [record_id]
                        };

                        //console.log('Serialized data: '+data);    
                        //$('div#rightSlider').offcanvas('show');
                        TASK.Ajax.Post(url, data, function(response) {  
                            $('div#rightSlider').find('div.rightSliderContent').html(response);
                            //$('div.offcanvas').offcanvas({canvas: 'body'}); // todo: make it work!
                            console.log('! edit one record form set up');    
                        });

                    }

                });

            //delete    
            $(row).find('td.delete-control').

                attr('data-source', '{{table.form.full_action_url}}?get_delete_form').
                attr('data-canvas', 'body').
                attr('data-target', '#rightSlider').
                attr('data-toggle', 'offcanvas').

                click(function () { 
                    if (!right_offcanvas_visible) {

                        //request form with ajax
                        var url = $(this).attr('data-source');
                        var data = {
                            'choose_record': [record_id]
                        };

                        TASK.Ajax.Post(url, data, function(response) {  
                            $('div#rightSlider').find('div.rightSliderContent').html(response);
                        });

                    }

                });

        {% endif %}


        {% if table.form.rendered_in == 'page' %}
            //on same page above the table

            $(row).find('td.edit-control').
                attr('data-source', '{{table.form.full_action_url}}?get_form').
                click(function () { 
                    console.log('! show edit form above table: '+record_id);    
                    var url = $(this).attr('data-source');
                    var data = {
                        'choose_record': [record_id]
                    };

                    TASK.Ajax.Post(url, data, function(response) {  
                        $('div#form-page-main').html(response);
                        $('html, body').animate({ //scroll smoothly to form
                            scrollTop: $('div#form-page-main').offset().top - config.scrollDistanceFromTop
                        }, config.timeAnimateToAjaxForm);
                    });

                });            


            $(row).find('td.delete-control').
                attr('data-source', '{{table.form.full_action_url}}?get_delete_form').
                click(function () { 
                    console.log('! show delete form above table: '+record_id);    
                    var url = $(this).attr('data-source');
                    var data = {
                        'choose_record': [record_id]
                    };

                    TASK.Ajax.Post(url, data, function(response) {  
                        $('div#form-page-main').html(response);
                        $('html, body').animate({ //scroll smoothly to confirmation
                            scrollTop: $('div#form-page-main').offset().top - config.scrollDistanceFromTop
                        }, config.timeAnimateToAjaxForm);
                    });

                });

        {% endif %}


        {% if table.form.rendered_in == 'modal' %}
            // rendered in modal window

            $(row).find('td.edit-control').
                attr('data-source', '{{table.form.full_action_url}}?get_form').
                attr('data-target', '#largeModal').
                attr('data-toggle', 'modal').
                click(function () { 
                    console.log('! show edit form in modal: '+record_id);    
                    var url = $(this).attr('data-source');
                    var data = {
                        'choose_record': [record_id]
                    };

                    TASK.Ajax.Post(url, data, function(response) {  
                        $('div#largeModal').find('div.modal-body').html(response);
                    });

                });            


            $(row).find('td.delete-control').
                attr('data-source', '{{table.form.full_action_url}}?get_delete_form').
                attr('data-target', '#smallModal').
                attr('data-toggle', 'modal').
                click(function () { 
                    console.log('! show delete form in modal: '+record_id);    
                    var url = $(this).attr('data-source');
                    var data = {
                        'choose_record': [record_id]
                    };

                    TASK.Ajax.Post(url, data, function(response) {  
                        $('div#smallModal').find('div.modal-body').html(response);
                    });

                });

        {% endif %}
```

I'm using Phalcon 1.3.3 TS on Windows (x86, PHP 5.4.19)

Any suggestions are very appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can start php inside volt and do those things, what volt don't provide.

i believe in future we will have

```
{% literal %} {% endliteral %} 
or
{% verbatim %} {% endverbatim %}
```

there is already NFR in github: https://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon/issues/1253

Now i can't find any wayout, just to use pure php in this part like:

```
...
<?php
 // your code like it would be simple *.php file
?>
...
```

Comment: {% literal %} does not exists on volt, nor {% verbatim %}